# MailKit I do not receive from the correct sender

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, mailkit

I use Mailkit in my contact form and everything works fine except filling the right mail from which is send to me. Every time the mail from and to is the same thing. The mail which I'm pointed out for my mail.
I tried with static string instead income input's but the problem is still there. Can someone help me.
I share the code below.
Thank you.
Best regards, Ventsislav

```
    public class MailKitEmailSenderOptions
    {
        public MailKitEmailSenderOptions()
        {
            this.Host_SecureSocketOptions = SecureSocketOptions.Auto;
        }

        public SecureSocketOptions Host_SecureSocketOptions { get; set; }

        public string Server { get; set; }

        public int Port { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 public class MailKitEmailSender : IEmailSender
    {

        public MailKitEmailSender(IOptions<MailKitEmailSenderOptions> options)
        {
            this.Options = options.Value;
        }

        public MailKitEmailSenderOptions Options { get; set; }

        public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
        {
            return SendEmailAsync(email, subject, message);
        }

        public async Task SendEmailAsync(string from, string fromName, string subject, string htmlContent, IEnumerable<EmailAttachment> attachments = null)
        {
            try
            {
                var message = new MimeMessage();
                message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(fromName, from));
                message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(this.Options.Username));
                message.Subject = subject;
                message.Body = new TextPart("html")
                {
                    Text = htmlContent,
                };

                using (var client = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    client.Connect(this.Options.Server, this.Options.Port, this.Options.Host_SecureSocketOptions);
                    await client.AuthenticateAsync(this.Options.Username, this.Options.Password);
                    await client.SendAsync(message);
                    await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an email server such as GMail, the server will replace the From header with whatever account you are using to send the message.

Comment: Hello, Is there a way to fix that?  It seems wrong...

Comment: No, there's no way to fix that - it is behavior that is hard-coded in the GMail SMTP server and is not something that a client can override.

Comment: Hello, I changed the server with another and right now when someone with email from gmail tried to send mail there is expection with message "invalid form address", there is no problem with other email suppliers. Is there a way to fix that?